# How to update an User with useMasterKey in Parse

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

#### Issue Description

I'm trying to update an User when another user click on my Xamarin button.
Then, I used Cloud Code to perform this but it doesnt work

#### My Code

Here is my complete JS code :

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("Archive", function(request, response) {
  Parse.serverURL = 'https://pg-app-0brffxkawi8lqvf2eyc2isqrs66zsu.scalabl.cloud/1/';
  var status = request.object.get("status");
  if (status == "validated") {
    var event = request.object.get("event");
    event.fetch({
      success: function(myEvent) {
        var coinsEvent = myEvent.get("coins");
        var user = request.object.get("user");
         user.fetch({
          success: function(myUser, coinsEvent, user) {
            var email = myUser.get("email");
            var coinsUser = myUser.get("coins");
            myUser.set("coins", coinsUser + coinsEvent);
            return myUser.save(null, {useMasterKey:true});
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
  response.success();
});
```

I think `myUser.save(null, {useMasterKey:true});` should work

I actually have that error :

> Dec 24, 2017, 12:27 GMT+1 - ERRORError generating response for [PUT] /1/classes/_User/1GPcqmn6Hd 
>   "Cannot modify user 1GPcqmn6Hd."
>
> {
>     "coins": 250
>   }

#### Environment Setup

- **Server**

  - parse-server version : v2.3.3
  - Server: Sashido

Comment: To help us to understand exactly where this error is coming from, please remove the bits of code that is not causing it.  See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Your success branch never calls `response.success()` which is a problem... though maybe not THE problem.

You are also doing 2 fetches inside a 'beforeSave' function which is not recommended.  'BeforeSave' must happen very quickly and fetches take time. I would consider thinking through other options.

If you really need to do it this way, consider doing a `Parse.Query("event")` with an `include("user")` and trigger the query with `query.first({useMasterKey:true})`.

Are you sure `coinsEvent` is what you think it is?  Fetch only returns the object fetched... not sure that you can curry in other parameters.  I would change your final success routine to (double checking that coinsEvent is valid):

```
 success: function(myUser) {
    var coinsUser = myUser.get("coins");
    myUser.set("coins", coinsUser + coinsEvent);
    return myUser.save(null, {useMasterKey:true}).then(_ => response.success());
  }
```

Comment: It works perfectly by adding "response.success()". Thanks a lot !!